# How do I insert a character after every n number of characters in a string using Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How do I insert a character (say an asterisk) after every n number of characters (say 100 characters) in a string using Redshift SQL

Answer (score 1):

This is not a normal capability of SQL.

However, you could [Create a Scalar Python UDF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-udf.html):

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_insert_char (s text, c text, gap int)
  RETURNS TEXT
STABLE
AS $$

  return c.join(s[i:i+gap] for i in range(0, len(s), gap))

$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Usage:

```
SELECT f_insert_char('The quick brown fox jumps over the foo', '*', 5);
```

Output:

```
The qu*ick br*own fo*x jump*s over* the f*oo
```

Use it in a query like this:

```
SELECT
  f_insert_char(column_name, '*', 5)
FROM table
```